# Check url for information with php

Tags: php, redirect

I am wanting to check the url of one of my pages if the user has landed correctly

for example if a user visits `www.example.com/page.php?data=something`

The user will beable to view the page

but if the user visits `www.example.com/page.php` he gets redirected

This is my current code

```
$checkurl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (strpos($check, "?data=")!==false){
         }
    else {
       header("Location: index.php");;
    }
```

I thought this would work and been at this for a while cant seem to see a problem but i am still learning...

Comment: You are checking an undefined variable named `$check`, when you should be checking `$checkurl`

Comment: :( thanks that fixed it, how did i miss it? thanks again :)

Comment: Still I would check the contents of the `$_GET` array instead.

Comment: yes im reading them now :), it does seem a easy way of doing things.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use $_GET

For example

```
if (!isset($_GET["data"])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

[PHP Manual $_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
if(isset($_GET['data']))
{
}
else
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
```

This way you just check if there is a "data" on your URL

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this since you are looking for a query string aka a `$_GET` request:

```
if ($_GET['data'] != 'something') {
    header('Location: http://test.com');
    exit();
}
```

Also, if you just want to check if they included `?data=`:

```
if (!isset($_GET['data'])) {
    header('Location: http://test.com');
    exit();
}
```